# Numpy multidimensional array, count inner arrays which are equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to compare two 3-dimensional arrays and count how many inner arrays are equal.

I'm comparing 2 patches of a picture and want to know how many pixels are equal and not how many color values are equal. And it would be nice if it's efficient so I'm using numpy. I know how to make the comparison with for loops but it's too slow.

But I'm only able to count it element wise, here's my snippet:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255]],

          [[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255]],

          [[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255]],

          [[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255]]])

b = np.array([[[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]],

          [[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]],

          [[0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]],

          [[0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]]])
print(np.sum(a[:, :] == b[:, :])) 
# prints 12 and i would like to have a 4 in this example
```

Comment: Shouldn't the desired answer be 4? I see 4 sub arrays equal

Comment: Yes of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether all three color values are equal for each pixel first and then count the pixels that are equal by summing up the trues:

```
(a == b).all(axis=-1).sum()
# 4
```

Comment: i have another question, maybe you can answer it. I want to check if there are equal with a small difference. In other words there are equal if the value is for example 10% off.